# How to extracting Data from HTML table using php

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I keep trying different methods of extracting the data from the HTML table such as using xpath. The table(s) do not contain any classes so I am not sure how to use xpath without classes or Id. This data is being retrieved from an rss xml file. I am currently using DOM. After I extract the data, I will try to sort, the tables by Job Title

Here is my php code

```
$html='';
$xml= simplexml_load_file($url) or die("ERROR: Cannot connect to url\n check if report still exist in the Gradleaders system");

/*What we do here in this loop is retrieve all content inside the encoded content, 
*which includes the CDATA information. This is where the HTML and styling is included.
*/

foreach($xml->channel->item as $cont){
    $html=''.$cont->children('content',true)->encoded.'<br>';   //actual tag name is encoded 
}

$htmlParser= new DOMDocument();     //to parse html using DOMDocument
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);   // your HTML gives parser warnings, keep them internal
$htmlParser->loadHTML($html);       //Loaded the html string we took from simple xml

$htmlParser->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tables= $htmlParser->getElementsByTagName('table');
$rows= $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach($rows as $row){
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    echo $cols;
}
```

This is the HTML I am extracting info from

```html
<table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='2'>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Job Title:</b></td>
    <td>Job Example </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Job ID:</b></td>
    <td>23992</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Job Description:</b></td>
    <td>Just a job example </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Job Category:</b></td>
    <td>Work-study Position</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Position Type:</b></td>
    <td>Work-study</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Applicant Type:</b></td>
    <td>Work-study</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Status:</b></td>
    <td>Active</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'><b><a href='https://www.myjobs.com/tuemp/job_view.aspx?token=I1iBwstbTs2pau+SjrYfWA%3d%3d'>Click to View More</a></b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you need to extract ?

Comment: Well, I need to parse all the data inside the table. I have many tables like this since this is an rss feed. The whole goal is to be able to reorganize all the tables to alphabetical order according to the Job Title

Comment: You need the text or the html inside `table` ? Please update your question with a sample of the desired output.

Comment: I will need the Html, I just need to be able to grab tag td to see what Job Title it is,  so I can sort accordingly.  I will update

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `xpath` to `query('//td')` and retrieve the `td` html using `C14N()`, something like:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$x = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach($x->query('//td') as $td){
    echo $td->C14N();
    //if just need the text use:
    //echo $td->textContent;
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
<td><b>Job Title:</b></td>
<td>Job Example </td>
<td><b>Job ID:</b></td>
...
```

---

[C14N();](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.c14n.php)

> Returns **canonicalized** nodes as a `string` or `FALSE` on failure

---

**Update:**

> Another question, how can I grab individual Table Data? For example,
>   just grab, Job ID

Use `XPath` `contains`, i.e.:

```
foreach($x->query('//td[contains(., "Job ID:")]') as $td){
    echo $td->textContent;
}
```

---

**Update V2:**

> How can I get the next Table Data after that (to actually get the Job
>   Id) ?

Use `following-sibling::*[1]`, i.e:

```
echo $x->query('//td[contains(*, "Job ID:")]/following-sibling::*[1]')->item(0)->textContent;
//23992
```

Comment: Excuse me, disregard  my last message. Thank You so much. I've been researching for a week to solve this. Can You direct me to some good resources for this type of parsing? Another question, how can I grab individual Table Data? For example, just grab, Job ID?

Comment: I'm sorry for asking so many questions, I just feel like you are the best resource I have came across from here. My last question about grabbing individual table data, such as Job Id, How can I get the next Table Data after that (to actually get the Job Id) ? As I said before, I have many tables, and each Job Id is unique, so how do i go to the next table data from the table

Comment: NP, check the new update. I'll go grab some food now ;) GL

Comment: These are some really esoteric and heady XPaths and on top of it, not very portable at all.  Woe to he who has to do this in more than one language -- or if the developer changes the name of a field, or adds a space between field name and colon, or eschews colons for something else...

Comment: Which **"other one language"** are you talking about?

Answer (score -2):

```
$xpathParser = new DOMXPath($htmlParser);
$tableDataNodes = $xpathParser->evaluate("//table/tr/td")
for ($x=0;$x<$tableDataNodes.length;$x++) {
    echo $tableDataNodes[$x];
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  I will try your solution as soon as I can Keith